# Java, copy array A to array B from index point using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I am trying to copy entries in the array `questionLineFields` to a new array called `testQuestions`.

I am trying to copy indices [1 to 3] in `questionLineFields` *not the value of [0] index.*

Here is my current code:

```
String[] A = new String[3];
String[] B = new String[]{"3","T","F","T"};
                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                        A[i] = B[i+1];                      
                    }
```

This does not work and I receive a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  I have seen this thread.  I would *preferably* use a for loop as my professor has requested use of a for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in a test now?

Comment: no, this is a weekly lab, just caught at this particular point

Comment: "_This does not work_" is much to unspecific. Describe the problem better if you want help. As I told you before: post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I receive a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Also in the link I specified below, the OP uses "doesn't seem to be working correctly" in his post.

Comment: @user2210274: This is vital information. Include it in the post. The error message is clear. You're trying to read or write from or to an index that does not exist in the array.

Comment: Always include the **complete** error message (and stacktrace).

Comment: Well I am also assuming since it is such a simple question everyone here, everyone would be able to see my error clearly.

Comment: Yes, I will in the future.  Instead of instantly down voting can you help me understand first? I am obviously open to learning how to be more clear with my questions as I am still learning.

Comment: No, we don't know what `questionLineFields` is exactly, so only an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) can help us help you here.

Comment: Yes, as said before: Include the complete error message (including stacktrace) and try to provide an example so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Just use simple variable names then.  B[i]=A[i+1] same question.

Comment: No, variable names are not the problem here. You're missing to show us some example input and expected output.

Comment: Exception is probably thrown from the access questionLineFields[i+1]; Pray show us how the array is populated, so we are better placed to help you.

Comment: Okay I will edit above.

Comment: Edited above, hopefully I did this right.

Comment: Your example does not reproduce the error. It runs without a problem.

Comment: Sorry still trying to get better at this.  I see, the array should be populated like above.  Well, I was doing my best to keep it short and concise.  People tend to get angry with too much code also.

Comment: @user2210274: Chances are very high you'll solve the problem yourself when writing the SSCCE. That's another good reason to write them before asking for help.

Comment: Are you looping through Array A; from i=0 to i=4? Remember, Array A[] only has 3 elements. I do not see, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in your current code.

So the only place would be while printing now?

Or just rebuild the project once again.

Comment: I was trying to navigate array B[1-3] and copy over to A[0-2].  Yes what jlordo said above actually helps as it points to a problem earlier in my code? I will try thanks

Comment: @JNL does looping through array A from 0 to 4 point to the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error I receive?

Comment: @user2210274 Yes, if you loop through Array A[], it only has 3 elements, you should loop from i=0 to i=2. (0, 1, 2) are 3 elements.

Comment: So that would cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [`System.arrayCopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) was made for

I'd put more into this answer but since you are at school you should probably figure it out for yourself ;)

Comment: could you show me how to do this in a for loop? Many thanks.

Comment: Or even a System.arrayCopy example would be helpful.

Comment: You need to learn how to read the Javadocs. Everything you need is right here. It tells you hwo to use it and what it does. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int)

Comment: i'll give you a hint that you should not use a for loop at all.

Comment: Well my professor requested we ONLY use a for loop.  Trying to start from the bottom.  Also I am not at school, this is a weekly assignment I am trying to do.